# Does Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 run on ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Official Rails site states it supports 1.8.x versions, but did anyone try to run Rails 2.3.8 on ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a search seems to reveal that it worked awhile ago on 1.9.2-head, so its likely that it does on 1.9.2.

See [Rails initializes extremely slow on ruby 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914037/rails-initializes-extremely-slow-on-ruby-1-9-1)